# Deploy to SFTP with visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sftp, web-deployment

I am having some trouble trying to deploy my website (an MVC4 WebApi service) to my server using SFTP. I am using VS2010 with the latest Azure SDK installed so I get the new Publish dialog.

What I do is select the site, put the address (keep in mind that the dialog does not permit the selection of a port here), set path and user name and pwd and then click Validate Connection, where it rolls for a while and then tells me that it could not find the server.

If I set the address with the port (:22) I get an error that the Rebex FTP does not support SSH and to use the other Rebex tool. I tried to add `sftp://` as well but in that case I get asked a password but no matter what I put in it just fails (I tried my domain pwd, the server pwd, the ftp pwd etc. to no avail).

Does anyone have any idea or had any success in the past deploying using SFTP? As a note I must add that connecting with a normal FTP client (Filezilla) works perfectly so the server is there, reachable and the pwd is right, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 4):

As near as I've been able to determine, the Publish mechanism in Visual Studio doesn't support SFTP. Nor does it appear to be extensible - so we can't build an extension to provide that support.

This has been a source of great frustration for our team. What I currently do is Publish to a local folder and then SFTP from there to the server.

I would be greatly interested in an SFTP solution [related to, or replacing the Publish feature] if anybody knows of one.

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I came across it while looking for an answer.

Answer:<strike>Visual Studio 2010 Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1</strike>

Answer: VS 2010 does not have SFTP, but VS.php plug-in has an option in php projects.

- Project->{Application Name} Properties
- Configuration Properties
- Expand to find Deployment
- Connection settings -> Deployment mode: set to Secure Ftp (SSH)

From there its just inputting your sftp info. I personally set my "Production" config to deploy to the SFTP and my local to just local.

Possible solution for SFTP is to use winscp & create a local repo of your server and pass builds to it. Afraid I don't have an example.
http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't seem to find the "Configuration Properties" option anywhere... got exactly that version of VS2010...

Comment: So sorry I messed up on the formatting xD

I was running a VS.php project I just realized. Seems like Shawn South's answer is correct, the Publish does not have a SFTP as an option.
An option that I've seen to get upload & download from server through SFTP was set-up http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_synchronize and basically have a local repo of your server